# Django: save many-to-many in a form

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I got such models:

Guests:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # ...
```

and meetings:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    # some fields ...
    guests = models.ManyToManyField(through='GuestOnMeeting')
```

A lot of guests can be in a meeting. And one guest can attend many meetings. And we are to store some additional information in relation. So, it is many-to-many through some model.

```
class GuestOnMeeting(models.Model):
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting)

    # ... some other fields
```

The questions are:

1. How do I define a form to edit meeting's guest list (invite guests - later we will use it to send sms-invitations - no spam, the guest are almost our friends;) ).
2. Every Guest has a manager (manager = models.ForeignKey(Managers)). How can I modify this form (or these models) to allow managers to invite only guests linked to them (with the foreign key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something like the admin inlines, you are looking for [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

```
>>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
>>> GuestOnMeetingInline = inlineformset_factory(GuestOnMeeting, Meeting)
>>> meeting = Meeting.objects.all()[0]
>>> form = MeetingForm(instance=meeting)
>>> formset = GuestOnMeetingInline(instance=meeting)
```

You can add [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset) or pass custom [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation) and/or [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-custom-queryset) to modelformset_factory.

Comment: inlineformset_factory takes 2 arguments:) what is the second?